# Why is (void)sizeof(param) not "using" param?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, language-lawyer, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a macro defined as follows:

```
#define UNREF_PARAM_1(a)
    do { \
        (void)sizeof(a); \
    } \
    while (0)
```

To get rid of compiler warnings. In a new project I am working on, VS2013 is suddenly complaining again about a unreferenced formal parameter.

Strangely it does work if I just use `(void)param`. 
Does anybody have a clue why it does not work when using it with `(void)sizeof(param)`?

Comment: `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: I generally avoid such macros, because, as code changes over time, people forget to remove them.  My preference is to comment out the name of the parameter in the function header, which suppresses the warning and makes it impossible to start using the parameter without updating the code.

Comment: I am using this macro for debug builds where I want some functions to do nothing and not get warnings about unreferenced parameters. For now I added a __pragma(warning(suppress:4100)) in before the (void)sizeof(a); instruction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in `sizeof(param)`, `param` is a so-called *unevaluated operand* and therefore not odr-used - that is, not needed at runtime.

However, `(void)param` does constitute a odr-use.

A cast with the notation in your code internally invokes a `static_cast`. [expr.static.cast]/6:

> Any expression can be explicitly converted to type *cv* `void`, in
>   which case it becomes a discarded-value expression (Clause 5).

[expr]/10:

> In some contexts, an expression only appears for its side effects. Such an expression is called a *discarded-value expression*. The expression is evaluated and its value is discarded. […] **The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied only if the expression is an lvalue of volatile-qualified type** […]

[basic.def.odr]/2:

> An expression is *potentially evaluated* unless it is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5) or a subexpression thereof. A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated
>   expression is *odr-used* **unless it is an object that satisfies the
>   requirements for appearing in a constant expression (5.19) and the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is immediately applied**.

The first part of this quote specifies that `sizeof(a)` isn't an odr-use of `a` since `a` is an unevaluated operand<sup>1</sup>.
Clearly `(void)a` is potentially evaluated. And because `a` is certainly neither allowed to appear in a constant expression nor declared `volatile`, no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is "immediately applied" and thus `a` is odr-used.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Here is a list of expressions where `x` is an unevaluated operand as from C++11:

- `typeid(x)`, where `x` is not a glvalue of polymorphic class type
- `sizeof(x)` (and `sizeof x`)
- `noexcept(x)`
- `decltype(x)`
- `alignof(x)`? `alignas(x)`?